# Stop VS excluding vspscc files

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I would like VS to automatically add vspscc files to TFS. (I know they're completely useless, but adding them solves another problem) (I also know I can add them manually one at a time but I have 170 to add).

Where is the list of extensions that are excluded and can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

For my problem I edited "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Configuration\VersionControl\LocalItemExclusions.config" and removed the entry `<Exclusion>*.vspscc</Exclusion>`.
I then ran `tf vc add` from the command line which successfully added all 170 missing vspscc files.